# Is it OK to do `Await Task.Run(Sub() SomeDatabaseUpdate() EndSub)

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous

Ah per the title, I have an application which does quite a lot of calls to a database doing updates and inserts.

I am doing things such as this:

```vb
Private Async Sub btn_Click() Handles btn.Click

    ' Get some values from user controls

    Await Task.Run(Sub()
                       SomeDatabaseUpdate(Value1, Value2, Value3)
                   End Sub)

End Sub
```

This has the effect of keeping the UI responsive and allowing my button to be pressed a few times and the work gets done even if one of the queries takes a while to execute (my insert query handles any duplicate entries).

However I've read that using `await` on a task without a return value should be avoided except for event handlers.

Are there any problems with this code that I should be aware of?

Comment: The thing to be avoided is awaiting on `Async Sub`, because of the way errors are handled (it's designed around event handlers as you note).  Awaiting on a function returning `Task` is fine, and that's what you're doing here---`Task.Run` is a function returning a `Task`, not a sub.  The only potential concern is that you're pushing the database update onto a thread from the pool; that's probably fine for a desktop app but might be a concern if you're writing for ASP.

Comment: You'd prefer to have an async option provided by the database, since that will be network and/or I/O driven, so it could support a "true async" instead of pushing to a background thread (see Stephen Cleary's "There is no thread" blog post for more on how this works).  But that depends on the library, it's not something you control.

Comment: Thanks Craig, I forgot that Task.Run() actually returns a Task... Duh! This is a desktop app, but why is this a concern for ASP (or at all?).

Comment: I don't have direct experience with this---read Stephen Cleary's blog posts on `Task`---but my recollection of his statements is, `Task.Run` appropriates a pool thread, but in ASP you really want to minimize use of threads off of the thread already used to service the request as consumption of threads hurts scalability.  I think there is also some concern of the scheduler not necessarily being prepared for this sort of consumption of pool threads (it expects thread per request).

Comment: See https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html (turned out I didn't have to poke around, it was on the post of his I have saved).

Comment: Thanks Craig, much appreciated.